Google Calendar appendPre is not defined
I use Google Calendar to write the itinerary according to the document, and it can be added to the calendar normally on the project, but it will prompt Uncaught ReferenceError: appendPre is not defined. Does anyone know why this is
enter image description hereenter image description here
I tried writing according to the document, but it still didn't work
 var event = {
        'summary': 'DCH Toolbox - Repair Appointment '+this.arr?.serviceDate.slice(8,10)+'/'+this.arr?.serviceDate.slice(5,7)+'/'+this.arr?.serviceDate.slice(0,4),
        'location': address,
        'description': 'Repair appointment Ref. code: '+this.arr.serviceOrderId+' has been confirmed.',
        'start': {
          'date': this.arr?.serviceDate
        },
        'end': {
          'date': this.arr?.serviceDate
        },
        'attendees': [
          {'email': this.arr.logisticsElectronicAddressLocatorEmail}
        ],
        'reminders': {
          'useDefault': false,
          'overrides': [
            {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60},
            {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10}
          ]
        }
      };
      tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
        client_id: clientId,
        scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
        callback: '', // defined later
      });
      gisInited = true;
      tokenClient.callback = async (resp) => {
        if (resp.error !== undefined) {
          throw (resp);
        }
        console.log('gapi.client',gapi.client);
        if(gapi.client.calendar) {
          var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
            'calendarId': 'primary',
            'resource': event
          });
          console.log('request',request);
          await request.execute(function(event2) {
            appendPre('Event created: ' + event2.htmlLink);
          });
        }
      };


you use appendPre in your code which is clearly a custom function as it's not standard JavaScript but you've not shown where it comes from. It needs to be defined or imported from somewhere. If you've not done this, then the error makes sense. Also, "I tried writing according to the document" what document??
